# How to delete messages from firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat application connected to firebase. I am trying to add a future where I can delete a message. This is what I have tried but it's not working.

This is the code

```
...package com.sollie.ian.eunice.ui


public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private RecyclerView recyclerChat;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_USER_MESSAGE = 0;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_FRIEND_MESSAGE = 1;
    private ListMessageAdapter adapter;
    public String roomId;
    private ArrayList<CharSequence> idFriend;
    private Consersation consersation;
    private MessageInput editWriteMessage;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    public static HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmapAvataFriend;
    public Bitmap bitmapAvataUser;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        Intent intentData = getIntent();
        idFriend = intentData.getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(StaticConfig.INTENT_KEY_CHAT_ID);
        roomId = intentData.getStringExtra(StaticConfig.INTENT_KEY_CHAT_ROOM_ID);
        String nameFriend = intentData.getStringExtra(StaticConfig.INTENT_KEY_CHAT_FRIEND);

        consersation = new Consersation();


        String base64AvataUser = SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance(this).getUserInfo().avata;
        if (!base64AvataUser.equals(StaticConfig.STR_DEFAULT_BASE64)) {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64AvataUser, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bitmapAvataUser = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        } else {
            bitmapAvataUser = null;
        }

        editWriteMessage =  findViewById(R.id.input);
        if (idFriend != null && nameFriend != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(nameFriend);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerChat =  findViewById(R.id.recyclerChat);
            recyclerChat.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            adapter = new ListMessageAdapter(this, consersation, bitmapAvataFriend, bitmapAvataUser);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message/" + roomId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        HashMap mapMessage = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Message newMessage = new Message();
                        newMessage.idSender = (String) mapMessage.get("idSender");
                        newMessage.idReceiver = (String) mapMessage.get("idReceiver");
                        newMessage.text = (String) mapMessage.get("text");
                        newMessage.timestamp = (long) mapMessage.get("timestamp");
                        consersation.getListMessageData().add(newMessage);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(consersation.getListMessageData().size() - 1);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            recyclerChat.setAdapter(adapter);
        }



        editWriteMessage.setInputListener(input -> {
            String content = input.toString().trim();
            if (content.length() > 0) {
                //  editWriteMessage.setTex("");
                Message newMessage = new Message();
                newMessage.text = content;
                newMessage.idSender = StaticConfig.UID;
                newMessage.idReceiver = roomId;
                newMessage.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message/" + roomId).push().setValue(newMessage);
            }
            return  true;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra("idFriend", idFriend.get(0));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
            this.finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("idFriend", idFriend.get(0));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        this.finish();
    }
}

class ListMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Consersation consersation;
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmapAvata;
    private HashMap<String, DatabaseReference> bitmapAvataDB;
    private Bitmap bitmapAvataUser;
    private String roomId;

    public ListMessageAdapter(Context context, Consersation consersation, HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmapAvata, Bitmap bitmapAvataUser) {
        this.context = context;
        this.consersation = consersation;
        this.bitmapAvata = bitmapAvata;
        this.bitmapAvataUser = bitmapAvataUser;
        bitmapAvataDB = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == ChatActivity.VIEW_TYPE_FRIEND_MESSAGE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rc_item_message_friend, parent, false);
            return new ItemMessageFriendHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ChatActivity.VIEW_TYPE_USER_MESSAGE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rc_item_message_user, parent, false);
            return new ItemMessageUserHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ItemMessageFriendHolder) {
            ((ItemMessageFriendHolder) holder).txtContent.setText(consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).text);
            Bitmap currentAvata = bitmapAvata.get(consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).idSender);
            if (currentAvata != null) {
                ((ItemMessageFriendHolder) holder).avata.setImageBitmap(currentAvata);
            } else {
                final String id = consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).idSender;
                if(bitmapAvataDB.get(id) == null){
                    bitmapAvataDB.put(id, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user/" + id + "/avata"));
                    bitmapAvataDB.get(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                String avataStr = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                if(!avataStr.equals(StaticConfig.STR_DEFAULT_BASE64)) {
                                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(avataStr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                    ChatActivity.bitmapAvataFriend.put(id, BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length));
                                }else{
                                    ChatActivity.bitmapAvataFriend.put(id, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.default_avata));
                                }
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else if (holder instanceof ItemMessageUserHolder) {
            ((ItemMessageUserHolder) holder).txtContent.setText(consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).text);
            if (bitmapAvataUser != null) {
                ((ItemMessageUserHolder) holder).avata.setImageBitmap(bitmapAvataUser);
            }
            ((ItemMessageUserHolder) holder).txtContent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("Delete Message");
                    builder.setMessage("Are You Sure To Delete This Messgae");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            deleteMsg(position);
                        }


                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void deleteMsg(int position) {

        final String myuid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String msgtimestmp =String.valueOf(consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).timestamp);
        String message=consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).text;

         DatabaseReference roofRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
         roofRef.child("message").child(message)
                 .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).idSender.equals(StaticConfig.UID) ? ChatActivity.VIEW_TYPE_USER_MESSAGE : ChatActivity.VIEW_TYPE_FRIEND_MESSAGE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return consersation.getListMessageData().size();
    }
}

class ItemMessageUserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtContent;
    public CircleImageView avata;

        public ItemMessageUserHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtContent =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textContentUser);
            avata =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        }
    
    
    }

class ItemMessageFriendHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtContent;
    public CircleImageView avata;

    public ItemMessageFriendHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtContent =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textContentFriend);
        avata =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    }
}
```

**And this is what I have tried**

```
private void deleteMsg(int position) {
    final String myuid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String msgtimestmp =String.valueOf(consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).timestamp);
    String message=consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).text;

     DatabaseReference roofRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
     roofRef.child("message").child(message)
             .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         }
     });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Frank, it worked well, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String message=consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).text;

DatabaseReference roofRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
roofRef.child("message").child(message).removeValue()
```

You're trying to delete the message based on its **text**, but to delete a node from Firebase you need to know its **key**.

This means that when you read the messages from the database, you'll need to store `dataSnapshot.getKey()` for each message (probably as a field in your `Message` class). Then when you are ready to delete the message, you can get the key from that class and pass it into the database call, with something like:

```
String key= consersation.getListMessageData().get(position).key; //  

DatabaseReference roofRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
roofRef.child("message").child(key).removeValue()... //
```